Unable to run Windows Sandbox after upgrade to 24H2
After upgrading to Windows to 24H2, I'm unable to run Windows Sandbox, as it is stuck on the splash screen. There are no errors in the logs.
What i have tried so far:

Uninstall and install the Windows Sandbox and Hyper-V feature
Enable Containers-DisposableClientVM Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName "Containers-DisposableClientVM" -All -Online
DISM DISM /Online /Cleanup-image /RestoreHealth
sfc scan sfc /scannnow
bcedit bcdedit.exe /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto

Edition: Windows 11 Enterprise
Installed on: ‎17.11.2024
Version: 24H2
OS build: 26100.2314
Experience: Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.26100.32.0

Workaround, if you can't fix it: use a free third-party tool such as Sandboxie, https://sandboxie-plus.com/, or alternatives: https://alternativeto.net/software/sandboxie/

Try re-enabling the Sandbox in Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or off
Uncheck Windows Sandbox and click OK, then restart your computer.
Then follow those same steps again and re-enable Windows Sandbox and restart again.
If this doesn't work you can also try:
dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:"Containers-DisposableClientVM" -All

Also restart Sand Box-related services by pressing win + R and typing services.msc and look for below services then right click on them and click on restart.
Hyper-V Host Compute Service
Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management
Windows Sandbox Network Virtualization Service

Have you read my question? As for everything that you propose I already tried.
